# Ruby: Prompting for multiple inputs

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get multiple inputs and assign it to different variables (in the irb) but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm only able to do it for the first variable, but for the next three, the last input gets assigned to the other 2 (I have 4 in all)

What I'm trying to do is, based on the first input (say, 2), it'll prompt for 3 more inputs 2 times.

```
t = gets.to_i
```

This is the first input and it gets assigned properly. 
It'll then prompt for 3 more inputs, but then only the last input gets saved and is assigned to all three variables.

```
a = gets.to_i
b = gets.to_i
k = gets.to_i
```

it'll accept 3 inputs but only the last gets saved?

say if I enter (for the first iteration)

```
1
10
3
```

after the first prompt (which i entered 2)
a, b, and k has value 3

```
t = gets.to_i
a = b = k = []

for i in 0..t-1 do
  a[i] = gets.to_i
  b[i] = gets.to_i
  k[i] = gets.to_i
end
```

Is it because it's in a loop? I'm putting it there since it has to ask for the values of a, b and k for t times where t is the first input.

I'm not sure if I explained it properly but I hope someone can understand what I was trying to do

Comment: Hint: how many arrays do you create in your code? There are two ways to create an array, using an array literal (e.g. `[]`) or by calling one of the `Array` factory methods (e.g. `Array::[]` or `Array::new`). Count the number of calls to factory methods and count the number of array literals in your code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I see it now. Thank you!! (esp for not answering it explicitly) :) I appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to address a variable in Ruby is by reference. That said,

```
a = b = k = []
```

declares three *references* to *the same object*. To fix it, declare arrays separately:

```
t = gets.to_i
a, b, k = [], [], []

for i in 0..t-1 do
  a[i] = gets.to_i
  b[i] = gets.to_i
  k[i] = gets.to_i
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* `for` loop is not ruby idiomatic. Use e. g. [`Range#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each) instead (or [`Integer#upto`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-upto)):

```
(0...t).each do |i| # or 0.upto(t - 1) do |i|
  a[i] = gets.to_i
  b[i] = gets.to_i
  k[i] = gets.to_i
end
```